# Storing deltas in the database instead of the whole object

Tags: .net, sql-server, bigdata, database

I would like to store/update an object with a long list of fields in database. I am planning to use SQL Server (not 2016) and I have no predefined data format to store this object which means I can store it in JSON/BSON, as a binary blob and etc.

However, for each update I would like to keep the changed parts instead of storing the object as a whole. With each request only a few of these items will be changed and similar to event sourcing I would like reapply all these changes in order to get the final version of the object. I have some constraints listed below:

- Besides updating the values for the existing fields the object may subject to changes in the future. New fields can be added or even existing ones can be deleted. I should be able to handle this scenario. It is possible that the current object may be quite different than the one we had when we last updated an item in the DB. I saw [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) which looks interesting.
- Of course there should be balance between performance and space saving. However, space saving is more important than the speed.

I read about json patch and some custom solutions to this kind of problem, but want to know more about this topic. However, I do not want to reinvent the wheel, but a method easy to implement (if there is a library/framework support its better of course) would be good.

Comment: Putting aside many other things to consider (such as how long it will take to rebuild the object from deltas): please take a look at the concept of sparse columns and column sets https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx - maybe this could help.

Comment: I think you are pretty much describing Event sourcing (ES) and Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS). So study up on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx

Comment: @RobertMoskal, you are right and also I mentioned it in the question (ES is fine no need to CQRS I think). However, I do not have a specific event here. I just get the diff of an object, which is subject to change in the future. May be I can define an event for each of that object and say Event X comes with value Y to mean an update in the example field "Name" to set its value to "Foo". However, this can suffer from the different versions of the object and I have to create a new event for each field. Not very good for maintainability.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this approach recently and it works. I can convert a large object mesh to an array of deltas and then convert it back to the object mesh accurately. The real questions are whether it's practical to store all that data, and then you do rehydrate it, whether performance is too bad to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are pretty much describing Event sourcing (ES) and Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS). So study up on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx

Changes to your JSON object can be described in a little command language. It could be as simple as:

```
set(property,value)
```

and store that in the database. If you only have the one command, you can avoid storing the verb at all.

You'll probably want to allow key paths or .dot notation in your property names to access nested items

```
 set('foo.baz.bar',{one:1})
```

But you may feel the need to introduce additional verbs to indicate events like setting the root of the object or deleting a key.

Replay the changes to materialize your entity. Read up on performance issues so you can come up with the best implementation for your use case.

Comment: What if we changed layout of the object we keep in the db and the information in the database had not been updated after that change. Serialized information in the DB may not be compatible with the current object. How can I understand that (versioning or something like that)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You change "the layout of the object" with a command and that command is applied to the database.  The database representation is always the single source of truth.  

I could see a client not being apprised of the change, not being able to manipulate the data.  

I'd be happy to chat for a few minutes on the topic.

Comment: I am planning to serialize/deserialize an object to/from json. Therefore, object I would like to store may change by time. For example, I can add a new member and etc. However, one of my records may not contain anything on that (ex: no add command in the history due to the inactivity on that record). The schema of the json is not related with the actual object anymore.

Comment: This is a general problem in these scenarios.  Your clients can be "smart and forgiving" when they don't get the data they expect.  Your clients can simply "fail" when they don't get what they need.

You can also use compensating transactions to go back and transform all your entities as needed. You can run those as batch process.

You'll probably use a mixture of all three techniques.

Comment: I see, may be versioning may help in that scenario? However, I have to keep every version of the object also in order to serialize/deserialize. Moreover, I have to make a conversion between them whenever necessary.

Comment: Sure versioning can help too.  Its' another way of keeping your clients in sync.  This may especially be helpful if you are marshalling the json back into c# objects.  I was assuming you were using a dynamic language where this wouldn't be an issue.  You can use versioning or compensating transactions to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123278/discussion-between-deniz-and-robert-moskal).